# Rails 4 - Wicked pdf file send via email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, pdf

In rails 4, I am using `gem 'wicked_pdf', '1.0.3'` and
`gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '0.9.9.3'` for pdf generation. I am downloading it as a file,

```
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render :pdf => "#{@user.id}_file",
      :disposition => "attachment",
      :save_to_file => Rails.root.join('public/download_pdfs', "#{@user.id}_file.pdf"),
      :layout => false
  end
end
```

Here, I am sending this file via mail by adding this line in controller `Email.deliver_sample_file_mail(@user, "#{Rails.root}/public/download_pdfs/#{@user.id}_file.pdf")`

In mailer,

```
def send_invoice_pdf_mail(user, file_path)
  filename = file_path.split("/").last
  attachments["#{filename}"] = File.read(file_path)
  mail(:to =>user.email, :subject => "File has been sent") do |format|
    format.html { render :partial =>"/emails/users/sample", :locals=>{:user=>user}, :layout=>"email"}
  end
end
```

Now the issue is both download file and email send is happening together.

How can I avoid file download feature? And how can I generate `.pdf` file so that it should send only to an email id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save file as below without download

```
pdf = render_to_string pdf: "#{@user.id}_file", encoding: "UTF-8"

# then save to a file
save_path = Rails.root.join('public/download_pdfs','#{@user.id}_file.pdf')
File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
  file << pdf
end
```

Hope, this will Help you.

Comment: remove "template: tmplates/pdf", statement.

Comment: you can set "redirect_to" method at end of same controller method, for achieve same.